# Contradiction between Beit Yosef and the Shulchan Aruch in O.C. תקנז

Tags: tefilla, minhag, tisha-bav, shulchan-aruch, mincha-afternoon-prayer

In siman תקנז of orach chaim there seems to be a contradiction between the [bet yosef](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2601) and the [mechaber](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2918) about when one says the תפילה of נחם on ט' באב. In the bet yosef he writes that one only says it at מנחה whereas in the shulchan aruch he seems to say that one says it at all the תפילות of ט' באב. How can one explain the difference between the two opinions?

Answer (score 5):

The Beit Yosef doesn't say to say it only at מנחה. He brings opinions on both sides and doesn't state his own opinion. I think this might have caused the confusion: When he says ושפשט המנהג כדברי רבינו סעדיה, he is quoting from the רד"א, and not saying that his own opinion is to say נחם only at מנחה. You can see the language here (highlighting the part where he quotes the opinion of רבינו סעדיה):

> וכתב א"א ז"ל כל ימי תמהתי למה אין אומרין אותה אלא בתפילת המנחה וכו'. בפרק בתרא דתעניות ורבינו ירוחס (ני״ח ח״ב קסל ע״ג) כתב שכדברי הרא״ש עיקר והכל בו (סי׳ סב ט:) כתב סתם דבכל תפילות ט"ב אומריס אותה אבל
>    הרוקח (סי׳ שיב) כתב אין מתפללין נחם בברכת ירושלים אלא במנחת ט"ב **והרד״א (עמ' רנז) כתב שהוא מחלוקת בין רב עמרם (סדר רב עמרם ח״ב סי׳ צח)
>   ורבינו סעדיה (עיי' סדור רס״ג עמ' שי״ח הערה 6) ושפשט המנהג כדברי רבינו סעדיה שאינו אומר אותו אלא במנחה** ונראה לי שטעם רביני סעדיה משוס
>    דלעת ערב הציתו בו אש הילכך באותה שעה מזכירין שפלות ירושלים ואבליה ומתפללין על תנחומיה וז״ל הריטב״א בתשובה (סי׳ סג) לענין נחם בט' באב
>    דעתי כיון דמשוס המאורע אמרינן ליה על פי הירושלמי לאמרו בכל תפילותינו ערבית שחרית ומנחה ככל מעין המאורע שבכל מקוס אלא שבערבית
>   ואינו בנחמה אומרים רחם ולמנחה אומרים נחם שדומה למי שנקבר מתו ומ״מ ש״צ אינו אומרו אלא במנחה
>   ושחרית שהוא כמי שמתו מוטל לפניו ואינו בנחמה אומרים רחם ולמנחה אומרים נחם שדומה למי שנקבר מתו ומ״מ ש״צ אינו אומרו אלא במנחה
>    כמו שנהגו עכ״ל:

In the Shulchan Aruch, he simply decided according to the Tur, quoting the Rosh, to say it in all of the prayers.

Comment: part of what made me look this up was that i saw in the machzor ish matzliach for tisha bav it said to only say nachem at mincha like the opinion of the bet yosef. that would seem to say that many sefaradim understand the bet yosef as saying to only say it at mincha.

Comment: @YosefMordechaiColeman I searched on the internet and found only sites that quote the Beit Yosef as I did. ["וכן פסקו מרן השלחן ערוך"](http://www.dvar-tora.co.il/mamr.aspx?id=613), and ["וגם יש נוהגים להגיד 'נחם' בכל שלוש התפילות כפסק מרן ה'בית יוסף'"](https://sites.google.com/site/rabbinissimperetz/home/parasha/9av_71#_ftnref2). What exactly did the machzor say?

Comment: In the ish matzliach it says מנהג ירושלים לומר כאן נחם בכל תפילות ט' באב. אך מנהג העולם לומר נחם רק בתפילת מנחה של יום ט' באב וכן היא בב"י.

Comment: @YosefMordechaiColeman I think the machzor might just be saying וכן היא בב"י about both of the opinions, since both are quoted by the Beit Yosef

Comment: today i looked at the the yalkut yosef and there he writes that to only say it at mincha is the opinion of the bet yosef. I also saw that as the opinion of Rav Mordechai Eliyahu so both Rav Ovadia Yosef and Rav Mordechai Eliyahu understood the bet yosef as only having it said at mincha.

Comment: @YosefMordechaiColeman I don't have that book, but [this site](http://www.yalkut.info/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F-%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%96-%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9D-%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%A0%D7%95-%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%98-%D7%91%D7%90%D7%91/) doesn't give it in the name of the Beit Yosef (and even implies that the sefaradi custom is to say it all day). I don't know what they are relying on for the opinion of the Beit Yosef (unless there's a responsa or something else he wrote)

Comment: Rav Ovadia also paskens that one says it at all of the tefillot of tisha bav like the opinion in the shulchan aruch but he notes that the bet yosef in the bet yosef says to say it only at mincha

Comment: @YosefMordechaiColeman I don't know what to say, since I don't see it there